# Batch File Not Looping for Non-File Items in a List

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Within an elevated command using Windows 10, I run this batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%G in ("3D Objects,Documents,Downloads,Music,Pictures,Videos") do (
echo %%G
)
```

I expect it to list each of those six items. Instead, it lists only the first one (3D Objects), and then stops. Using "Tokens" doesn't seem to make much difference, and "delims" doesn't seem to be functioning as I thought it would.

**Question:** Am I mistaken in thinking that `FOR` can handle comma-delimited items in a list?

Comment: A later question develops this question further: https://superuser.com/questions/1487512/batch-unexpected-variable-results-in-subroutine

Comment: The `for /F` loop does not iterate over tokens, it loops over lines; the six tokens you specified are returned by `%%G`, `%%H`, `%%I`, `%%J`, `%%K` and `%%L` for each line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is working as you expect for a non-file list because as indicated within `for /?`. . .

- > ```
  > FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
  > FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
  > FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
  > ```

I believe this means the `FOR /F` handles either `command`, `string`, or `file-set` which I presume `file-set` specifically means an actual file. If this is the case, then that means putting the non-file list within there, it's interpreted as being a string which the `delims` and `tokens` cannot parse or iterate.

---

To resolve put the non-file list within a regular [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop without using any `tokens` or `delims`, and ensure values which contain a space are enclosed with double quotes.

```
@echo off
cls
for %%G in ("3D Objects",Documents,Downloads,Music,Pictures,Videos) do (
echo %%~G
)
```

You could put double quotes around all values and use the [`~`] tilde in the variable placeholder to parse out the double quotes from the output value giving the desired output without double quotes.

```
@echo off
cls
for %%G in ("3D Objects","Documents","Downloads","Music","Pictures","Videos") do (
echo %%~G
)
```

#### Output

```
3D Objects
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Videos
```

### Supporting Resources

- [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: @RayWoodcock I just added some additional detail, let me know if this is along the lines of what you are looking for. I gave an explanation why I believe this is not working as you desire and then a method using similar logic you are using to give you the desired output.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. The FOR documentation you quote doesn't seem to contemplate a list of this type. Your tilde option provides a working solution. Many thanks! (I'm editing to add those double quotes in your suggested code, so as to produce the listed output.)